# HaGaon HaRav Asher Weiss Shelita and Techelet

Tags: rabbis, tzitzis, techeles

Does anyone know if [HaRav HaGaon Asher Weiss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osher_Weiss) wears Techelet?

Also, why or why not?

Comment: Is this the same person? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osher_Weiss

Comment: Some hints for places to look.  http://www.mhcny.org/parasha/1037.pdf

Comment: @avi yes this is that person

Comment: Here is a list of audio lectures by Rav Weiss about Tzitzis. I must confess I did not listen to them all the way through and what I did hear did not mention Tachelet, but I still thought they might be interesting in this context. Enjoy. [Rabbi Asher Weiss on TzitTzit](http://bcbm.org/index.htm)
Go to link, go to Bamidbar, Shlach, and there you will find the list of shiurim.

Comment: Although the question was already answered, why do you care to know if he does?

Comment: http://en.tvunah.org/2013/12/16/tcheiles-from-murex-truncules/

Comment: Curious, what made you think he did?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He does not. (My Brother In Law learned in his Yeshiva).

Comment: We now also have his Shu"t cheek 2 which he writes exclusively that we need not wear it

Comment: Prob a better source than my anecdote @sam. Do you have link to the source?

Answer (score 2):

He does not wear techelet as he is not sure that the murex trunculus is the chilazon of the techelet. He does admit [here](https://youtu.be/-ZTuXxY2hZQ) that the chilazon is a snail.

He also says he doesn’t [oppose](https://youtu.be/HyBRw0vp564) anyone from wearing techelet as he explains there is no downside to wearing the murex trunculus.

He just thinks he has no obligation to wear it as there is a safek in his mind. He doesn't apply the concept of safek d’oraita l’chumrah even when there is a safek whether you did the mitzvah or not unlike the Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: More precisely he feels strongly the murex is **not** the chilazon, not that he's unsure

Comment: He says we probably won’t know for sure until Mashiach  in the video. He apparently doesn’t accept any archeological evidence and he has not seen the direct naming of the murex as the chilazon in the Yerushalmi and some acharonim. Somewhere who spoke to him told me that he feels much softer on the issue than when he wrote the teshuvah but he won’t change his psak although he says there is no downside to wear it.

Answer (score 1):

He does not. He feels that archaeology cannot change a halacha and therefore we need not concern ourselves with the shaila. See Rabbi Aryeh Lebowitz here who address this: http://www.yutorah.org/sidebar/lecture.cfm/857737/rabbi-aryeh-lebowitz/ten-minute-halacha-why-do-so-many-gedolim-still-not-wear-techeiles-/

Comment: Hello ShmuelRefael, welcome to Mi Yodeya!

Comment: The recording of his I've heard isn't quite that, it's that the archeology is inconclusive; techeles was a rare thing, so the common murex factories are probably something else, such as argaman. In essence, we are searching under the lamppost.

Comment: @Shalom I heard a similar idea in the name of Rav Moshe Heinemann here. He added that the murex blue or purple was extremely expensive, so it's not surprising that the gemara suggested indigo as the cheap alternative, not murex.

Comment: @Shalom Techelet was a expensive commodity, but not a rare thing so that it would not come from an organised production. The Gemara clearly says the chachamim  prefered to get their techelet from the city of Luz, but that implies there were other sources. Morderchai was dressed in techelet by the Persian king, so the gentile kings had access to techelet. Additionlly, we know the Roman emperors limited and finally banned any trading of murex related products which included our argaman and techelet.

Comment: @GershomMenachem you are welcome to disagree, but please don't shoot the messenger -- I'm quoting an mp3 of his. He says specifically that Mordechai shows that it was very rare and reserved for royalty (at least in large quantities).

Comment: Yes, it was reserved for royalty at the time of the Rambam who says that techelet was in the hand of the melech goyim, but obviously the chachamim of the Talmud were able to source it from Luz and the Gemara says techelet could be found in the market , so had to make sure it was done lishma